# Custom Clone Button - Default values to blank

Tags: javascript, case, button, clone

I would like to create a custom clone button on the case object that clones all of the case but I want two fields - Escalation_Stats__c, Escalation_2 to default to blank. Below is the code I am trying but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
/{!Case.Id}/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&clone=1&{!Case.Escalation_Status__c}
=&!Case.Escalation_Type__c}=
```

Comment: (comment posted incorrectly; removed)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response but I have found a work-around using URL-Hacking. For custom fields you need to use the Lead id for this, for example:

/{!Case.Id}/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&clone=1&{!Case.Escalation_Status__c}
=&001J000001aKS8t=&001J000001aKIRJ=

This will clone the button, then default the two custom fields to blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Create a Visualforce page that will receive the event ID and the controller of this page will retrieve the data from this ID and fill in the fields according to the recovered data.

In your button, you can redirect the user to the page or you can open this Visualforce in a jQuery dialog.

To open a jQuery dialog, visit this link:[here](http://www.valnavjo.com/blog/modal-dialog-on-a-standard-salesforce-page/)

Comment: I would create a flow, lookup the current record, thwn use the create new element and set the necessary fields to blank

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have found a work-around using URL-Hacking. For custom fields you need to use the Lead id for this, for example:

/{!Case.Id}/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&clone=1&{!Case.Escalation_Status__c}
=&001J000001aKS8t=&001J000001aKIRJ=